# Object outlines suddenly clearer partway through render (Eevee) DOP issue?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, depth-of-field

I've rendered 2 animations in Eevee, and they both have a similar problem where at first the subject of the animation has a nice sort of light wrap/depth of field soft edge sort of thing or I don't know what. But suddenly on one frame this will stop, and from then on the outline of the object is perfectly clean. I want to stop this from happening, I'd rather keep the softer edge as it feels more integrated and realistic.

Here are examples from my 2 renders, flip between the frames to see the difference:

[image: render 1 before pop]

[image: render 1 after pop]

[image: render 2 before pop]

[image: render 2 after pop]

I have the "cube with emissive volume" fog trick going on, which I doubt is the problem. It covers the whole scene so there's no point where the boat is entering or leaving it. I have a hunch this is something to do with depth of field, so here are my camera and render settings:

[image: camera settings]

[image: render settings]

And lastly I have some compositing which involves the glare node, which I suppose could also be part of the issue. The noise isn't indicative of the cause of the issue, I have jitter turned on in the lens distortion node because I found it to be a quite pleasing substitute for film grain. I tested without Jitter and the problem remained. Here's my compositing set up:

[image]

Other things of note are that I'm running Blender 2.91.0 on a Dell XPS laptop with 32GB of ram, an i9 2.9GHz and an NVidia GTX 1050 Ti. Both renders are lit purely by the HDRi with a modified horizon. Between the 2 renders, the issue happens at different points in the duration of the animation and at different distances from the camera. In both renders there is a sphere empty closely following the boat for focus. It mainly affects the boat, but you can actually see it also affects the horizon line and basically everything in the image. I speculate it's either some weird issue with depth of field, or perhaps me maxing out some kind of memory allocation? Rendering animation in Cycles is simply not an option for me, I love Eevee and I really want to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.